# Do double-chin reduction exercises work?

Tags: exercise, neck

I got suggested some exercises to reduce my double chin. They normally involve tilting the head back and, looking at the ceiling, and either making a tense kiss in the air or sticking the tongue out for some seconds, or putting some tension on the neck muscles, like when pushing the under jaw forward. An alternative are neck rolls.

Do these exercises work? Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A double-chin is a collection of fat, so in order to get rid of it, you need to reduce the amount of fat.

Now, there is no way to target where you want to burn fat. You burn it all over your body, or nowhere at all.

Thus, the best way to get rid of double-chins, is to take a look at your diet, which is the number one way to reduce fat naturally.

If, after losing a lot of fat, you still have a semblance of double chins, it could be residual skin, which is something that is most commonly fixed with minor, non-invasive surgery.

As for the exercises you mention, I have tried to find some sources for it, but all I can find are some articles here and there, written purely for clicks.

Some of them involve slapping your chin, pinching your chin, and doing a bunch of - let's be honest here - stupid stuff.

Notably, none of them source any actual research, so as far as we know, some dimwits are actually writing these articles for clicks and ad-revenue.

So no, all evidence suggests that this is all bullshit.

Bottom line: If you have too much fat, you should adjust your diet.

Answer (score -1):

Of course fat may be an element, but so are lax muscles. It is definitely possible to target muscles and make them stronger, thus tightening the tissue and diminishing the look of a double chin. There are plenty of slim people with double chins!
It's the same as facial muscles. If you work them regularly, you'll reduce the sagging that comes with age, or at least hold it off for a few more years than the average person. Yes, a lot of the exercises look and feel silly, but they do work. How can that basic logic be denied? A lot of regular gym exercises look kind of silly when you think about it, but should that prevent someone from trying them? 
Good information and products are out there, but unfortunately yes, there are many useless sites and products available. Do research, continue to ask questions.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say Alec has provided a brilliant answer. It's true, there's no way to target a specific area for fat reduction. Your overall body fat should reduce, in order to reduce fat from anywhere.People who sell products to melt love handles or belly fat, or techniques to reduce double chin, are usually frauds. They just need money, and sell things that never works. Workout and bring about a change in your diet, and above all, change your body if you feel like changing it. Don't do it to impress others. Just live up to your own expectations. 
Peace.